# Can't get GeometryNodes to bake into a texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, geometry-nodes

im trying to use GeometryNodes to make a ground texture with pebbles scattered everywhere, but i have a problem where these instanced pebbles get completely ignored in the cycles baking process ( the selected to active method ), but renders correctly if i bake from the camera or just use cycles rendering in the viewport.
I've checked for the usual stuff, like rendering being disabled for the object and visibility options in general, but i really cant find a solution to this.
Is this a known problem? Im using blender 2.93.5.

EDIT: i found something new, apparently geometry node based modifications of the mesh such as subdivisionsurface actually show up in the baked image, what gets ignored is everything related to the "point" nodes, so in my case "pointDistribution" followed by "pointInstance".
The weird thing is that it also keeps the previous modifications right before the first point node, so while the subdivision surface doesnt show in the viewport, it does in the final baked image, as if blender decided to skip the point nodes entirely.

What it looks like in the viewPort (base mesh is a cube (also ignore the triple geometry output))
[image: Viewport]

What it looks like after baking

[image: Bake]